# Conditionally excluding spring data jpa repositories

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration, repository, spring-data-jpa

We are using `spring` + `spring data jpa repositories` + `maven` as build environment. We deploy our project wars on multiple cloud environments.

For a particular cloud environment, we retrieve the login credentials from database.
For ex. For `AWS` we may have `AWSCredentials` domain object and `AWSCredentialsRepository`
For `Azure` we may have `AzureCredentials` domain object and `AzureCredentialsRepository`.

Is there a way in spring data jpa that we can conditionally load repositories using some parameter from build script?

For ex: I want to deploy to azure cloud. So i would require only `AzureCredentials` domain and `AzureCredentialsRepository` but not `AWS`.

Is there an elegant way to do this in `spring`?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I think this will work with java-config.
(I had to replace applicationContext.xml with this voodoo to get "optional jpa repositories" to work.

I was not able to find an applicationContext.xml .. xml IoC answer to this problem.

In my case, I wanted local developers (spring-profile=default) to use an H2 database to store some info, but the "real code".... non default spring profiles...would hit a redis-cache.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses =
        {com.mystuff1.MyJpaRepository1.class, com.mystuff2.MyJpaRepository2.class})
@Configuration
/* jpa:repositories (di.xml) does not support being wrapped in a spring-profile-attributed-bean.  this class is a workaround */
/* we only want InternalFhirBundleProviderWrapperJpaRepository "scanned in" as a JpaRepository .. when the spring-profile of "default" is specified.  */
@Profile("default")
public class JpaReposInASpecificSpringProfileVoodooWhereWaldoJavaConfig {
}
```